# Шаблонизация HTML файла в PHP формат

Tags: php, html

У меня есть готовый шаблон в html формате при открытии index.html в браузере все нормально работает но мне бы хотелось поработать c php с этим файлом например сделать index.html в формат index.php но когда делаю формат файла php дизайн шаблон сайта пропадает почему так происходит можно ли вернут дизайн сайта подскажите пожалуйста

ссылка шаблон сайта
https://colorlib.com/polygon/kiaalap/index.html

формат файла при html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

формат файла при изменении в php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не так сайт запускаете на xampp. должно быть либо `localhost/kiaalap....` либо сразу `kiaalap....`

Comment: спасибо @АлексейШиманский

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не так сайт запускаете на `xampp`. Должно быть скорее всего вот так

```
localhost/kiaalap-master/index.php
```

либо сразу

```
/kiaalap-master/index.php
```

в зависимости от того как настроили сервер. Но скорее всего первый вариант

И, конечно, сервер должен быть запущен))

---

P.S. Можно в `httpd-vhosts.conf` дописать:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@blog.local
    DocumentRoot "C:\my_projects\blog.local\www"
    ServerName blog.local
    ServerAlias www.blog.local
    ErrorLog "C:\my_projects\blog.local\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\my_projects\blog.local\logs\access.log" combined
  <Directory "C:\my_projects\blog.local\www">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

И тогда можно в браузере обращаться `blog.local` без префикса `localhost`

в вашем случае, конечно все пути надо заменить на свои и название проекта тоже

Answer (score 0):

У вас не полноценный шаблон, а всего лишь его дизайн.
Каждому своё, но я бы посоветовал для начала выучить начальный уровень PHP и JS, а уже после заниматься тем, что вам нужно.

Ко всему этому - вы не используете сервер и PHP, а пытаетесь локально открыть файл с расширением .php, что не есть хорошо, ведь браузер не знает, что такое PHP.

Как это работает? Вы запускаете веб-сервер на определенном порту, а далее с этим портом начинает работать интерпритатор PHP.

Но ответ на ваш вопрос. Установите локальный веб-сервер, для начала я бы посоветовал Open Server Panel. Администрация проекта ужасна, но сам сервер работает отлично. С его помощью и научитесь использовать PHP.